# Remove Duplicate Records from one Table with foreign keys in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'Directors' and another table 'company_directors'.

In the directors table there are duplicate records with the same "fullname", I want to select just the one with the longest "address".

and I want to update the foreign key "directorID" in the 'company_directors' table.

I have tried to use GROUP BY but i have no way of specifying which of the duplicates I want to keep... I also do not know how to go about updating the foreign key records to reflect the selected 'director_id' of the duplicates.

## Update:

I have been able to flag the duplicate records as inactive by altering the 'directors' table and adding an 'active' column. 
 However I still want to correct the references in the 'company_directors' table, before deleting the inactive/duplicate records.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please give us more details about the tables and records. Example data, table structure, what did you tried? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Alter table add a column nullable int called keep. Set to 1 if it us the one u want to keep

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in-place, then update the second table first.

```
update company_directors cd join
       directors d
       on cd.DirectorId = d.DirectorId join
       (select fullname,
               substring_index(group_concat(directorId order by length(Address) desc), ',', 1) as newDirectorId
        from directors
        group by fullname
       ) dnew
       on d.fullname = dnew.fullname
    set cd.DirectorId = dnew.newDirectorId
    where dnew.newDirectorId = d.DirectorId;
```

Then, update `directors` by deleting the uninteresting directors:

```
delete cd
    from directors d left join
         cd.DirectorId = d.DirectorId join
         (select fullname,
                 substring_index(group_concat(directorId order by length(Address) desc), ',', 1) as newDirectorId
          from directors
          group by fullname
         ) dnew
         on d.fullname = dnew.fullname and d.directorId = dnew.newDirectorId
    where dnew.newDirectorId is null;
```

I'm not thrilled with this approach, because `newDirectorId` (in both queries) ends up being a string rather than a number.  But, MySQL doesn't support window functions, so this is possibly the simplest approach.

That said, I would encourage you to take a slightly different approach.  First, backup the tables before you do anything.

Then, instead of deleting from `directors`, add a flag indicating whether the record is active.  Then, inactive the records with shorter addresses.  Investigate the results to be sure they are what you want.  Manually change the flag where it is not correct.  Then, go back to the `company_directors` table and fix the records that point to inactive records.

Comment: I agree that this is not the best approach however i have been handed down the database with this problem and manual solutions would be too hectic as it contains thousands of records a little over 4500 records actually. I'm currently trying to use your above soulution but it keeps giving me "0 rows affected" on the update statement.

Is there a way to implement the flags without having to do it manually for each record?

Comment: When i use a `select` like this
 `select * from company_directors cd join
       director d
       on cd.director_id = d.director_id join
       (select full_name,
               substring_index(group_concat(director_id order by length(address_personal) desc), ',', 1) as newDirectorId
        from director
        group by full_name
       ) dnew
       on d.full_name = dnew.full_name
   -- set cd.director_id = dnew.newDirectorId
    where dnew.newDirectorId = d.director_id;`

it displays the records without the duplicates.

NB: I commented `set` statement when using `select`

Comment: help/suggestion please?